# JavaFX AreaChart Clear Data

Tags: java, charts, javafx, series

i create a Object of a extended Area Chart. In this Area Chart is a dataSerie if the object is created. Later i will add 3 New Data Series to the Area Chart and the first dataSerie musst be deleted.

How can i delete the first dataSerie?

```
areachart.getData().addAll(s1, s2, s3);
```

Here you can see how i add the new Series into the areachart, but first i want to delete the old ones...

Thanks for your help

---

So now I know it! I can use the following Statement:

```
areachart.getData.remove(....)
```

But this makes another Question open! How can i get the total added Series of the Area Chart.
How can I get the information of how many series in the Area Chart are?

Comment: [`getData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#getData--) returns an [`ObservableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) of Series, so you can call any method defined in `ObservableList` or in [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), such as [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--), [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself.
You can do something like this:

```
areachart.getData().removeAll(m_histogram.getData());
```

It will remove all kind of data inside the area chart!!